# display: table on mobile - height issue

Tags: html, css

I have a modal window: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/mwLbw11k).
While browsing on mobile (OS: Android/iOS, browser: Chrome), when I open modal and scroll background page to bottom, I have next problem: when the [top browser toolbar with URL input and tabs button hides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybRZg.png), there is a white space under the modal.
[image]
The black wrapper on the screenshot is made by `.modal-mask`.

```
.modal-mask {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  display: table;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}
```

And it does not fit the full window height and width. You can see white space on the bottom and on the right. So `.modal-mask` doesn't cover all `<body>`. How can I make `.modal-mask` always being full height and width?
By the way, there is no such problem on desktop.

P. S. My modal is centered on the page yet.

Edit 1: gif.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to use another unit on `width` and `height`.

CSS:

```
.modal-mask {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9998;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw; /* vw mean viewport width */
    height: 100vh; /* vh mean viewport height */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    display: table;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
}
```

To use viewport width/height can guarantee the overlay mask set the width and height as 100% of viewport size.

Comment: Sorry, didn't helped me for now. Tried on both mobile device and desktop (but with device toolbar).

Comment: You need to hide the device toolbar?

Comment: when the [browser toolbar](https://i.imgur.com/tcaADL0.png) is hidden (as a result of scrolling down), I need to have `.modal-mask` full-height and full-width anyway.

Comment: I don't know what is your `body` css setting, but my suggestion is set position as relative on body with 100vw&vh. Then `.modal-mask` remove `display: table`. In my projects, its work for me.

Comment: 100vw/100vh is a lot! Take into consideration that the viewport height/width are calculated: `(Desired size * 100) / Viewport basis = size in vw`. This means your screen is 1000px wide and you want your content to be 20px wide: `(20 * 100) / 1000 = 2vw`.

Comment: @Samson I've updated my question with better explanation.

Comment: Can you please share or simulate it on codepen or jsfiddle? It is hard to know what's wrong on your code now. Is that the top jsffidle is yours one?

Comment: That's mean you need to make the page no scroll?